# Issues with using arrays C++

Tags: arrays, arduino, gpio, arduino-c++

Sorry to bother you but I have been having issues getting my a motor array to output in this code here.

```
// initialise motors

// Motor 1
//int in1 = 4;
//int in2 = 2 ;
// Motor 2
//int in3 = 8;
//int in4 = 7;
// Motor 3
//int in5 = 12;
//int in6 = 13;
// Motor 4
//int in7 = 9;
//int in8 = 10;

// Array of PWM's
int thisPin = 0;
uint8_t pwms[] = {3,5,6,11};
byte numberPwms = 4;

// Array for output channels
// Motor 1 (4 = High, 2 = Low)
// Motor 2 (8 = High, 7 = Low)
// Motor 3 (12 = High, 13 = Low)
// Motor 4 (9 = High, 10 = Low)
int mtrpin = 0;
uint8_t motors[] = {4,2,8,7,12,13,9,10};
byte motorPin = 8;

void setup()
{
//  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in5, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in6, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in7, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(in8, OUTPUT);

  for (pwmPin = 0; pwmPin < numberPwms; pwmPin++){
      for (mtrPin = 0; mtrpin < motorPin; mtrPin++){
            pinMode(motors[mtrPin], OUTPUT);
        pinMode(pwms[pwmPin], OUTPUT);
        };
    }; 
}


void motorLoop(){
// setting the direction to turn and speed

//  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); // Motor 2
//  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
//  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); // Motor 2
//  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);  
//  digitalWrite(in5, HIGH); // Motor 3
//  digitalWrite(in6, LOW);
//  digitalWrite(in7, HIGH); // Motor 4
//  digitalWrite(in8, LOW);

// Set the speed for the Motors

  for(int pwmPin = 0; pwmPin < numberPwms; pwmPin++){
      for (mtrPin = 0; mtrpin < motorPin; mtrPin++){
            pinMode(motors[mtrPin], LOW);
        analogWrite(pwms[pwmPin], 200);
      };
   };  
};

void loop()
{
  motorLoop();
  delay(500);

}
```

I have managed to get the initial call to work but I am now turning it all into arrays.
I have managed to get it to work for the PWMs but now after adding the motors array it has stopped working and gives this error message.

In Function 'Void setup()';
41:8: error: 'pwmPin' was not declared in this scope
42:11: error: 'mtrPin' was not declared in this scope
 In function 'void motorLoop()';
74:8: error: 'mtrPin' was not declare in this scope.

I know the error will probably be really simple but I can't find to save my life.

Also the for loops have been called as they are now and separate and I am still getting the same errors.
You can see this code at https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fFQKRTjhDrb-motor-initial-turn/editel.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Break it down into smaller parts. It's always a good idea to build often when writing code, not write a bunch and then hit build. Write a function, build. Add more code to that function, build. And so on.

Comment: Check the case of your variables. C++ is case-sensitive (as the error implies)

Comment: There is no `byte` type in `c++` (except `std::byte` from `c++17`). You probably want to use `unsigned char`

Comment: @Rhathin byte is a standard type in [Arduino-C++](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/byte/)

Comment: Great thanks everyone. Managed to get it working. Never thought to check if the values were correct to case sentive. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
In Function 'Void setup()'; 41:8: error: 'pwmPin' was not declared in this scope 42:11: error: 'mtrPin' was not declared in this scope In function 'void motorLoop()'; 74:8: error: 'mtrPin' was not declare in this scope.
```

As the compiler says: `mtrPin` has not been declared, and yet, you are using it.

Declarations introduce names in a program, like the name of your variable `mtrPin`. Other examples are namespaces, functions and classes. A name **must be declared before it can be used**. You **cannot** refer to a name which is declared later in the code.

```
int mtrPin; // this is a (uninitialized) declaration -> mtrPin can be used
int mtrPin { 0 }; // this is a (value) initialization -> mtrPin can be used
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I have managed to get it working now as it turned out to be a case sensitve problem. Thanks for your feeback :D